# Getting element id from Controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to add the element id in Angular,

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control input-sm"
                        id="ruleResetType"
                        name="ruleResetType"
                        ng-model="rule.resetType"
                        ng-options="data as data for data in Type"
                        ng-required="true"
                        ng-disabled="isEditable(id)">
                </select>
</div>
```

I wonder if is it possible to add **id** at isEditable(id)", I mean the id shall be the element.id?

Comment: Do you mean that id would be "ruleResetType"?

Comment: It's possible, but it's hard for a reason: because using id's is not good Angular practise. It couples your view to your controller tightly. Instead, use some property on the scope, or even just `ng-disabled="isEditable('ruleResetType')"` in the markup.

Comment: yes, but I want not to write the id, I looking for something programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but like Greg says, you probably don't want to use the element id.

```
app.directive("disableIfIn", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            disabledElements: '@disableIfIn'
        },
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if(scope.disabledElements.indexOf(attrs.id) === -1){
                element.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then (assuming the existence of disabledElements on your scope and elements are disabled by default) add this attribute to your HTML elements:

`disable-if-in="{{disabledElements}}"`